# Rows with NaN values

Tags: python, dataframe, function

I am wondering how to first define a function (Name: Rower) in Python with a single input, a pandas DataFrame, and that counts how many NaN rows the input has.

I don't know how to start, especially how to define the function in the first place.
I am very very new to python and would be happy if you could add also an explanation.

Here is a sample of what I've tried:

```
def pandasNull(df):
    return df.isna().sum().sum() 

df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(6,4), index=[1,2,3,4,5,6], columns=['A','B','C','D'] ) 
example_df = df[df>0]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In order to help, it's important that you show some effort in having tried to solve the problem yourself.  What you describe seems like built in capabilities of pandas and there would be plenty of examples on here of how to do that.  Try some of those, and if they don't work show us example of data, the code you tried, and what doesn't work so we can help.

Comment: So what I tried: 
def pandasNull(df):
    return df.isna().sum().sum()

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(6,4),
    index=[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    columns=['A','B','C','D']
)
example_df = df[df>0]
example_df

But this gives only the data frame, and what I want to display are only the number of rows with at least one Nan

Comment: `example_df.isna().sum(axis=1)`  Is this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer here depends on whether you want to count the rows that have NaN entries in any column or only the rows that have NaN entries in all columns.  Below I've defined two functions, one for each operation, and created some sample data.

```
import pandas as pd

def rower_any(df):
    return df.isna().any(axis=1).sum()

def rower_all(df):
    return df.isna().all(axis=1).sum()

sample_data = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c',), ()]
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=('x1', 'x2'))
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
    x1      x2
0   a       1.0
1   b       2.0
2   c       NaN
3   None    NaN
```

Calling these functions on our sample data, `rower_any(sample_df)` = 2, `rower_all(sample_df)` = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the input value to a string and compare it to the string representation of NaN, such as:

```
if str(row["column_name"]) == "nan":
    count += 1
```